How to use Pydantic types with sqlalchemy and asyncpg
Using: Sqlalchemy 1.4 & Pydantic v1
Sqlalchemy + asyncpg query:
async def get_api_key(
    db_session: AsyncSession,
    api_key_id: ApiKeyId,
) -> ApiKey | None:
    if api_key_id is None and auth0_id is None:
        return None
    result = await db_session.execute(
        select(ApiKey).filter(ApiKey.id == api_key_id,)
    )
    return result.scalar_one_or_none()

Sqlalchemy model:
class ApiKey(Base):
    id: Column = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
    )

Pydantic models:
class ApiKeyId(ConstrainedStr):
   # Validate value here

class ApiKey(BaseModel):
    api_key_id: ApiKeyId

When using psycopg2, this works perfectly, but when using asyncpg, the following error occurs: error = DataError('invalid input for query argument $1: ApiKeyId(abcdefgh... (Expected unicode, got ApiKeyId)')
The easiest solution is just to add str() to the ApiKey.id in the query. However, is there a better way to do this?

After investigating further, I think str() is probably the best approach.

In psycopg register_adapter is the equivalent but the closest equivalent in asyncpg register_codec doesn't work for Python custom types.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275337/is-there-a-register-adapter-found-in-psycopg-equivalent-function-in-asyncpg/
